# how to make a database secondary on mysql server..?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way of making a database offline/down/inactive/secondary  on MYSQL SERVER ...so that when we query like `SHOW DATABASES` it will give us the list of active/online/primary databases....?
Also making these databases down/secondary will affect the synching  with other database servers?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not a database, it's a schema (`show databases`). You can down the whole instance but not schema.

Comment: thanks for ur reply...can you tell me how we can make the whole instance down....?